# C++/Linux: Dynamic Allocation produces two different error messages

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

Here is a simple C++ program which takes in a size arguments and allocates an array of integers of that size. program is compiled using g++ under Linux running on a virtual machine with 32bit architecture.
When the application is called with argument (array size) above 1073741823* I get

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

error and with a value slightly smaller than that I get.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc Aborted (core dumped)

here is the code:

```
/* dynamicAlloc.cpp */
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> //for atoi
#include <cstdlib> // for rand() and srand()
#include <ctime> // for time()

using namespace std;
#define STR_LEN 256

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(0)); 

    unsigned int iArraySize = 1;
    if(argc < 2)
        return -1;

    iArraySize = atoi(argv[1]);

    int *pnValue = new int[iArraySize];
    if(pnValue == NULL)
    {
        cout << "cannot allocate array" << endl;
        return -2;
    }

    for(unsigned int iCounter = 0; iCounter < iArraySize; iCounter++)
    {
        pnValue[iCounter] = rand(); 
    }

    delete[] pnValue; 
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting two different errors?

also if I have a very big data that requires billions of data to be processed/massaged, do I have to use a database to handle such large amount of data or is there another method of handling large data sets?

thank you for reading

*1073741823 = (2 ^ 32(bit address)) / 4(int size in byte)) - 1

## UPDATE

The output of ulimit -a is:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3808
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3808
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The Ram size is configured to be 512MB. I thought since every program has it's own virtual page (for a 32bit arch it's 4GB I think) then I can use all of that virtual memory.

Comment: So you have 512MB of (virtual) RAM, meaning that, if a 4GB allocation could even succeed (which it can't for various reasons on a 32-bit platform), you would also need 3.5GB of swap to cover for the rest of the allocation. How much swap does your VM have configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have 4 gigabytes of memory available to you on a 32 bit machine. You have 4 gig total. What your program can access is less than that.

You get a segfault with that huge value because you are creating an illegal address. The underlying machinery doesn't even get a chance to try to allocate that memory. It goes kaboom before even attempting to make the allocation.

With a slightly lesser value, the address is valid but something is preventing you from allocating that large a chunk of memory. You might not have that much memory, or you might have a limit that prevents you from taking that much memory. If it's a soft limit you can raise it. If it's a hard limit, you need sys admin privileges to raise it.

Comment: To add a bit to this - you have a total 4GB address space. Under Linux, the usual case is that 1GB of that is reserved for the kernel, leaving you 3GB. In that 3GB, you have your program code, data and stack, the code and data for any shared libraries that are in use, and a few other things (guard pages, `mmap()`ed files, etc.). So realistically, even for a minimal program, allocations much above 2.5GB are going to be problematic, and probably considerably smaller than that, due to where the various other things are usually allocated.

Comment: So If I run multiple instances of the same program I will get the same error with smaller values?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `ulimit -a` to see what is the current heap size and maybe also `ulimit -s unlimited` and then check if your program starts behaving better? Also how much RAM is dedicated to the virtual machine?

Also why do you think you can take all 32bit address space? You do have kernel and other stuff loaded in memory.

Comment: I answered your questions above. Thanks for teaching me the commands btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

With a 32 bit system, you can address 4 GiB. If you try to allocate more you get a segmentation fault from the system. When you allocate less than 4 GiB, `new` throws an exception, because it can't allocate this much. There's also static data and stack, which take up space in the 4 GiB address space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to know my current limit in allocating space? If I need more for some reason, how do I get more?

Comment: There are several limits: `ulimit`, system limit like the 1/3 GiB split in linux, hardware size. You can look at `/proc/meminfo` or the command `free` to see your total memory. If you need more, you might modify your algorithm to use disk space. Sort does this for example, if the file(s) to sort are too big to fit into memory.